# how to scrape text between data-bind?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the name that is within the html code

```
<h3><a data-bind="'attr': { 'href': PersonURL }, 'text': PersonName" 
    href="/bios/mbaxter">Michael N. Baxter</a></h3>
```

The code I have is bellow

```
url="https://www.morganlewis.com/our-people-results?pagenum=1&sortingqs=Last%20name&pagesize=500&currentGroup=36ef4ad43dea406895fa2d41af32fada&filtergroup=Office&loadCategories=true&param_sitecontentcategory=OUR%20PEOPLE&schoolsearchstring=villanova&subCatInfo=Office,36ef4ad43dea406895fa2d41af32fada&subCatText=Office%20%3A%20Philadelphia"
tag='h3'
cls="data-bind"
def name_scrape(url,tag,cls):
    page=requests.get(url) 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    #print(soup.prettify())
    find_name=soup.find_all(tag,class_=cls)
    for entry in find_name:
       print(entry)

name_scrape(url,tag,cls)
```

it seems like the name is within the class 'data-bind'. How do I make sure that i am able to scrape the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of that site are heavily dynamic. So, you have two options: either go for using any browser simulator like `selenium` or use the right url containing json data. The latter is undoubtedly the best way.

This is how you can grab them (the easy way):

```
import requests

url = "https://www.morganlewis.com/biosearchnew/execute?pagenum=1&isInternalBioRequest=false&SortingField=Last%20name&currentGroup=36ef4ad43dea406895fa2d41af32fada&loadCategories=true&param_sitecontentcategory=OUR%20PEOPLE&pagesize=500&schoolsearchstring=villanova&personofficeitem_sm=36ef4ad43dea406895fa2d41af32fada"

res = requests.get(url)
for items in res.json()['SearchResults']:
    print(items['Title'])
```

Partial response:

```
Lindsay Ann Barci
Michael N. Baxter
Jeannine T. Bishop
Jeffrey P. Bodle
Sarah E. Bouchard
Brandon J. Brigham
Amanda M. Bruno
Evan W. Busteed
```

Comment: how did you locate the right url with the json data?

Comment: Use dev tools (I use chrome) to get the link. In it's network section there is a tab xhr. Select that tab, reload the page and find the link it produces.